# Img won't load on Twitter Bootstrap Homepage

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a small twitter bootstrap site run on RoR (I am new to coding).  I am in the process of getting an image on my homepage.  Here is the file path assets/views/pages/home.html.erb file .  Here is the only html code in my home.html.erb file

```
<body>
  <img src="../images/ctclogo.png" alt="logo">
</body>
```

ctclogo.png is the correct spelling of my image in my images folder.  I wasn't sure if I only needed /images/ctclogo.png for my path, so I tried multiple paths from various sources I read online and continue getting the little img icon representing an image.

Could something else possibly be wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the line

```
<img src="../images/ctclogo.png" alt="logo">
```

with

```
<%= image_tag 'ctclogo.png', alt: 'logo' %>
```

Also, make sure your image is in the `app/assets/images` folder.

Comment: Luis, thanks so much.  Is that "Ruby"?  Just trying to wrap my head around that.  Does standard html not work in a html.erb file?

Comment: It's the rails way to display an image, you should not use standard html in your case.